# ExoPlayer can't play audio/video streamed (RTMP) by Adobe live stream encoder

Tags: android, rtmp, live-streaming, exoplayer2.x

I'm using `Adobe Live Stream Encoder` to stream `RTMP` live audio in server side.
in my android client app, `ExoPlayer` with RTMP Extension can't play it and causes `RtmpIOException` but I can play it with VLC or MPC.

I tested my android app with some other `RTMP` links and it was Ok.

I also used this url in other video players installed in my phone (MxPlayer, Vlc) and it was Ok.

this is the code in android for playing video:

```java
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();     

TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory();
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

//Create the player
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
playerView.setPlayer(player);
MediaSource videoSource = null;

Uri uri = Uri.parse("rtmp://172.18.49.6/live/11");

dataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory();
videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);

player.prepare(videoSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

And this is the exception:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
net.butterflytv.rtmp_client.RtmpClient$RtmpIOException
    at net.butterflytv.rtmp_client.RtmpClient.open(RtmpClient.java:56)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.rtmp.RtmpDataSource.open(RtmpDataSource.java:60)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:885)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with it, try modifying this on the RTMP URL:

```
Before:
Uri uri = Uri.parse("rtmp://172.18.49.6/live/11");

After:
Uri uri = Uri.parse("rtmp://172.18.49.6/live/11 live=1");
```